# Indent by exactly one space

Tags: python, notepad++, indentation

I have written a large block of code in Python that I just realized is indented exactly **three** spaces (not four!)  Using *Notepad++ as my IDE*, I cannot find any way to indent exactly one additional space to make it line up with everything else.

I imagine there is some way to write a macro to shift everything by one space, but I have little intention on mastering Notepad++'s macros just for this one case.  Perhaps there is even a setting I missed?

Is there a non-manual way to indent to the proper alignment (adding one space)?

Comment: use the find and replace for regular expressions. So search for 3-space characters `^\s{3}[^\s]` and replace it with four spaces.

Comment: HAHAHA, oh that's painfully simple.  I cannot believe I didn't think of that.  Write that up as the answer, and I'll accept it when possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to write up the comment as an answer (as asked by the OP).

---

You just need to do a find and replace with a Regular Expression that matches for 3 space characters at the beginning of a line and replace it with four characters. So the pattern to match would be something like `^\s{3}[^\s]`.

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1:**

- Search Replace
- Search Mode - Regex
- Find what ^\s
- Replace with <2 space characters>

**Option 2:**

- Do a block select of all the columns. For block select, use ALT + SHIFT followed by dragging your mouse all the way from start to end
- Add as many spaces as you want

Comment: That would replace any line that started with two space characters and ensure that it now starts with three characters. You would need to match for exactly three space characters followed by a non-space character.

Comment: @John: There shouldn't be a line with less than 3 spaces which is the minimum indentation, in this case

Comment: I'm not really sure how to perform that block select even after reading your option 2 instructions.  Do I need to hold the mouse button down while I drag?

Comment: @BlackVegetable: There was a Typo, it should be ALT + SHIFT rather than CTRL + SHIFT. And Yes, you have to hold the left mouse button while dragging

Comment: @Abhijit - There may not one less then three, but there could be 8, which by option one would then become 9.